# Получить список пользователей, количество успешных билдов у которых меньше числа неудачных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно посчитать результаты где builds_result.status = 'Done' и builds_result.status = 'Error' и вывести список пользователей у которых результат счета 'Done' будет меньше чем 'Error'

```
select users_info.user_id, 
       users_info.user_firstname,  
       builds_result.status,  
       count(builds_result.status) as kol_vo 
from users_info, builds_result, files 
where builds_result.file_id = files.file_id 
  and files.user_id = users_info.user_id 
  and builds_result.status = 'Done'
group by users_info.user_id, builds_result.status 
order by kol_vo desc
```

Comment: `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN builds_result.status = 'Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < SUM(CASE WHEN builds_result.status = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: @akina ставлю после group by выдает пустой запрос

Comment: Уберите отбор и группировку по статусу-то...

Comment: убрал все ровно пустой запрос

Comment: Тогда делайте fiddle. На нём и потренируемся... Достаточно одной синтетической таблицы - нужен-то только принцип.

Comment: @akina http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/de339
он должен вывести только  users_id = 1  user_firstname = FAVG

Comment: *он должен вывести только users_id = 1* ??? У него два Done и один Error, что не соответствует условию *'Done' будет **меньше** чем 'Error'*.

Comment: ошибся простите, спасибо все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select users_info.user_id
     , users_info.user_firstname
--     , SUM(CASE WHEN builds_result.status = 'Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Done count"
--     , SUM(CASE WHEN builds_result.status = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Error count"
from users_info
INNER JOIN files ON files.user_id = users_info.user_id 
LEFT JOIN  builds_result ON builds_result.file_id = files.file_id 
group by users_info.user_id, users_info.user_firstname
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN builds_result.status = 'Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < SUM(CASE WHEN builds_result.status = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5da4e2d78e5ad391d25d14785356bde5)